# Why my for loop for my curve returns `Inf` in R?

Tags: r, function, for-loop, plot

I'm trying to loop over 2 curves in R but only one of the curves shows. More importantly, I call `axis()` command two times (for x and y axes) but I get the following error:

`Error in axis(1, at = success/trials) : no locations are finite`

`'to' must be a finite number`

## Question

I'm wondering **(a)** why only my first curve is showing and **(b)** why I'm getting `Inf/-Inf` in my `axis()` calls?

**Here is my R code:**

```
success = c(10, 50) ; trials = 100

for(i in 1:length(success)){

success = success[i]
    col = (1:length(success))[i]

c = curve( dbinom(success, trials, x), 0, 1, add = ifelse(i > 1, T, F), ty = "l", xlim = c(0, 1), 
           col = col, yaxt = "n")

text(success/trials, max(c$y), bquote(bolditalic(H[.(i)])), pos = 3, xpd = T )

axis(1, at = success/trials)  

}

axis(2, at = seq(0, max(c$y), len = 7), labels = round(seq(0, max(c$y), len = 7), 2), las = 1 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first pass through the loop you set `success` to `success[1]` and in the second pass through the loop you set `success` to `success[2]` but `success` was at that point length 1, so it becomes `NA`.

Similarly, the second plot doesn't show because `col` becomes `NA` for the same reason.

To fix this, use a different name for the list of successes and the variable in the loop. For example, use `successes = c(10,50)` and then use `successes` when setting `success` and `col` inside the loop. (Alternatively for `col`, just set `col = i`.)

Applying that to your code:

```
successes = c(10, 50) ; trials = 100
for(i in 1:length(successes)){
    success = successes[i]
    col = i
    c = curve( dbinom(success, trials, x), 0, 1, add = ifelse(i > 1, T, F), ty = "l", xlim = c(0, 1), 
               col = col, yaxt = "n")
    text(success/trials, max(c$y), bquote(bolditalic(H[.(i)])), pos = 3, xpd = T )
    axis(1, at = success/trials)  
}
axis(2, at = seq(0, max(c$y), len = 7), labels = round(seq(0, max(c$y), len = 7), 2), las = 1 )
```

Comment: A follow-up question. How can find out the largest `max(c$y)` in `i`th round? That is, for example, in your answer, `max(c$y)` when `success` is **10** is larger than when  `success` is **50**, how can I find in which round of the loop, `max(c$y)` is larger?